# Including and using a XML layout all within an Android library jar

Tags: android, android-layout, jar, android-library, android-gradle-plugin

**I want to create an Android jar library which has activities which use layouts that are all within the jar file.**

I have been researching and trying different methods for the last few days and exhausted the related posts here. I have managed to get drawables and other raw assets to reside and be loaded from within the jar. However I have not been able to include valid resources which include the layouts. The official view is that it is not supported yet however I am sure it can be done.

I see that this is possible with .aar libraries when using Gradle but I am unsure if .aar libraries are compatible with older Android projects.

Could anyone shed some upto date info on this issue of resources/layouts in jar libraries and also the compatibility of .aar libraries.

Many thanks

Comment: "I have managed to get drawables and other raw assets to reside and be loaded from within the jar" - I would be very curious to know how you accessed them in you code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create an Android jar library which has activities which use layouts that are all within the jar file.

That is not possible, sorry. However, you are welcome to create an Android library project that serves this role, and that library project can ship a JAR instead of Java source code (see the Play Services SDK's library project for an example). The layouts would not be inside of the JAR file, though.

> The official view is that it is not supported yet however I am sure it can be done.

I am sure that you are incorrect in your assessment.

> I see that this is possible with .aar libraries when using Gradle but I am unsure if .aar libraries are compatible with older Android projects.

Project age has nothing really to do with it. If you are using Gradle, AAR files work. If you are not using Gradle, AAR files do not work.

Comment: Thanks, I had already read a lot of your answers on this subject but still had some hope :) 

What happened to your cwac parcel project?

Comment: @MattCarron: the Android Parcel Project was discontinued after we started using Android library projects for distribution. `cwac-parcel` is still floating around (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-parcel), though it is increasingly unnecessary. Also note that Maven has `apklib` files, which I am not especially familiar with, though I understand that they fill a similar role as do AAR files.